# saving cart details on orders table laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, cart

These are the cart details

```
$cart[$id] = [

            "name" => $food->food_item,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $food->price,
            "restaurant" =>$food->restaurant_id,

        ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);
```

I want when the user clicks a button place order to save these item details in orders table in their respective fields 
//create order

```
order= new Order;
```

how will i save the cart?

Comment: What do you mean by saving cart?

Comment: The cart is already saved in session, if you want to save the food order in database to avoid data loss on session flush then create the cart fields in your orders table and use Eloquent ORM to save the record like you normally would with anything else

Comment: am getting undefined variable $food @CaddyDZ

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a new instance of Order model. Then,

```
$order = new Order();

$order->food = $food->food_item;
$order->quantity = 1;
$order->price = $food->price;
$order->restaurant = $food->restaurant_id;

$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you want to save the order details. In other to do that, you need to create a relationship for `Order` and `OrderItem` so that when you save your `cart` details, it will save one order in `Order` table and save the order items in the `OrderItem` table.

You can do this way, get the cart.

```
$oldCart = Session::get('cart'); 
$cart = new Cart($oldCart);

$order = new Order;
$order->quantity = 1;
$order->price = $food->price;
$order->restaurant = $food->restaurant_id;
$order->customer_id = auth()->user()->id; // you can add this to tag the customer info
$order->save();

$orderItems = [];
foreach ($cart->items as $ItemId => $item) {
    $orderItems[] = [
        'order_id' => $order->id,
        'food_id' => $foodId
        'quantity' => $item['qty']
    ];
}
OrderItem::insert($orderItems);

});
```